# What is causing my NullPointerException?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

My program compiles perfectly, but whenever I try to run it throws a NullPointerException. I tried searching this up, and found that the error relates to some value being null while the program is trying to use it, but I re-checked everything and came up blank.

Here's the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) 
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) 
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:27‌​2)
```

The code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WorldsMostBoringGame
{ 
  public void main (String [] args)
  {    
    System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door and a key.");

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     boolean hasKey = false, doorOpen = false, amIDoneYet = false, monsterAlive = true;

    while (!amIDoneYet)
    {
      String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

      if (userInput == "look around")
        LookAround(hasKey);
      else if (userInput == "get key")
        GetKey(hasKey, monsterAlive);
      else if (userInput == "open door")
        OpenDoor(doorOpen, hasKey, amIDoneYet);
      else if (userInput == "kill monster")
        KillMonster(monsterAlive);
      else
        System.out.println(userInput+ " is not a recognized command.");
    }
  }

  public boolean GetKey(boolean hasKey, boolean monsterAlive)
  {
    if (hasKey == false && monsterAlive == false)
      System.out.println("You pick up the key.");
    else if (hasKey == true && monsterAlive == false)
      System.out.println("You already picked up the key.");
    else if (monsterAlive == true)
    {
      System.out.println("You must kill the monster first.");
      return hasKey = false;
    }

    return hasKey = true;
  }

  public void LookAround(boolean hasKey)
  {
    if (!hasKey)
      System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door and a key.");
    else
      System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door. You have a key.");
  }

  public boolean OpenDoor(boolean doorOpen, boolean hasKey, boolean amIDoneYet)
  {
    if (hasKey)
    {
      System.out.println("You unlock the door. Game over. You win.");
      amIDoneYet = true;
      return doorOpen;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("The door is locked. Find a key.");
      return doorOpen = false;
    }
  }

  public boolean KillMonster(boolean monsterAlive)
  {
    System.out.println("You kill the monster.");
    return monsterAlive = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could we see the error, including the line at which it occures

Comment: You must show us the line causing the exception. If you've done any searching at all, you'll know that this information is key towards solving it.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)

Comment: Additionally, don't try to compare strings with "==". See http://tinyurl.com/so-java-string-equality

Comment: I thought this is the first day since creation there is no `==` on Strings :(

Comment: Also you have bug, you shouldn't compare strings using `userInput == "look around"` instead use `equals()` method.

Comment: @user2928683: Well that's not in your code at all, and it looks like you're using a custom Java compiler. What happens if you try to compile that code with a normal Java compiler and run it?

Comment: No no no. Don't use `==` for String value comparisons. Use the `equals()` method. Like this `if ("look around".equals(userInput))`

Comment: I would give the line, but that's all the interactions pane shows. Don't worry about the other bugs, I havent been able to run and fix bugs yet. The program compiles fine. Ok, so i changed the string comparisons, and get the same error message.

Comment: `public void main (String [] args)` should be `public static void main (String [] args)`

Comment: Putting a (real) main method around this doesn't give me an exception (although it does lock me into an eternal "Command not recognised" loop because of string ==

Comment: Shouldn't all those methods be static?  Or are you instantiating the class from somewhere else?

Answer (score 15):

Add a `static` keyword to the `main` method so the application has a valid entry point

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
```

*Edit:*

Once this change is made create an instance of `WorldsMostBoringGame` such that the instance methods can be invoked:

```
WorldsMostBoringGame game = new WorldsMostBoringGame(); // create this instance
while (!amIDoneYet) {
   String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
    if ("look around".equals(userInput)) { // use String.equals
       game.lookAround(hasKey);
    } ...
```

Comment: How did you see that :|

Comment: Do add the info about using `equals()` method instead of `==` also. The user definitely needs to know that as well. :) And now that main is static, as a side effect, all the other methods need to be static as well.

Comment: Although this breaks everything else because main is written as if its not static. I renamed the existing main and recreated a new real main

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it! Made all the methods static, and runs like a champ.

Comment: @user2928683 I recommend creating an instance of `WorldsMostBoringGame` to avoid making those methods `static`

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WorldsMostBoringGame
{ 
  public static void  main(String [] args)
  {    
    System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door and a key.");

     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     boolean hasKey = false, doorOpen = false, amIDoneYet = false, monsterAlive = true;

    while (!amIDoneYet)
    {
      String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();

      if (userInput.equals("look around"))
        LookAround(hasKey);
      else if (userInput.equals("get key"))
        GetKey(hasKey, monsterAlive);
      else if (userInput.equals("open door"))
        OpenDoor(doorOpen, hasKey, amIDoneYet);
      else if (userInput.equals("kill monster"))
        KillMonster(monsterAlive);
      else
        System.out.println(userInput+ " is not a recognized command.");
    }
  }

  public static boolean GetKey(boolean hasKey, boolean monsterAlive)
  {
    if (hasKey == false && monsterAlive == false)
      System.out.println("You pick up the key.");
    else if (hasKey == true && monsterAlive == false)
      System.out.println("You already picked up the key.");
    else if (monsterAlive == true)
    {
      System.out.println("You must kill the monster first.");
      return hasKey = false;
    }

    return hasKey = true;
  }

  public static void LookAround(boolean hasKey)
  {
    if (!hasKey)
      System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door and a key.");
    else
      System.out.println("You are in a room with a locked door. You have a key.");
  }

  public static boolean OpenDoor(boolean doorOpen, boolean hasKey, boolean amIDoneYet)
  {
    if (hasKey)
    {
      System.out.println("You unlock the door. Game over. You win.");
      amIDoneYet = true;
      return doorOpen;
    }
    else
    {
      System.out.println("The door is locked. Find a key.");
      return doorOpen = false;
    }
  }

  public static boolean KillMonster(boolean monsterAlive)
  {
    System.out.println("You kill the monster.");
    return monsterAlive = false;
  }
}
```

change all the method to static, and "==" should n't used to compare composed type